# Elmah.io , can't see logs when accessing http://localhost:port/elmah

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah.mvc, elmah.io

I'm new to elmah.io, I'm trying to integrate it with an ASP.NET Mvc app.
The problem is that when I access the http://localhost:port/elmah I can't see the logs even if the errors are logged in elmah.io.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifgXS.png

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
....
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
....
<system.web>
   <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      </httpModules>
....
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
     <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
     <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
     <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
...
<elmah>
   <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
   <errorLog type="Elmah.Io.ErrorLog, Elmah.Io" apiKey="xxxxxx" logId="xxxxxxx" 
        applicationName="xxxx"/>
</elmah>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [elmah.io](https://elmah.io) offer its own UI with extended features not available on the ELMAH UI. You can enable the ELMAH UI by turning on the *Messages | Read* permission as shown here: [How to configure API key permissions](https://docs.elmah.io/how-to-configure-api-key-permissions/). I wouldn't recommend doing it since someone that got their hands on your API key then has access to read your error logs. So, sign in to elmah.io and browse your error logs there for a much better and secure solution.

Also, you should disallow remote access by setting `allowRemoteAccess` to `false`. With your current config, you allow everyone to look inside your error log (at least if you enable the read access as mentioned above).